# how to get currency symbol in twig, symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I am currently able to get currency symbol in symfony2 controller

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter($this->getRequest()->getLocale(),\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$symbol = $formatter->getSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);
```

and then pass it to twig.

However, because I need to get this currency symbol in many twig templates, inserting that piece of code in the corresponding controllers is not a pleasant thing to do. So, is there any better/easier way to do this directly in twig?

Thanks.

Comment: would a twig extension be ok?

Comment: you're right. i missed the twig extension cookbook. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I create the custom twig function

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;

class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            'currencySymbol' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'currencySymbolFunction'),
        );
    }

    public function currencySymbolFunction($locale) {
        $locale = $locale == null ? \Locale::getDefault() : $locale;
        $formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
        $symbol = $formatter->getSymbol(\NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);

        return $symbol;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

The service:

```
acme.twig.acme_extension:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Because I need to get and pass the current defined locale in symfony2 parameters.ini into the twig function, I define a global twig value:

```
twig:
    globals:
        locale: %locale%
```

And finally in twig template:

```
{{ currencySymbol(locale) }}
```

Comment: I like this however after implementing it, instead of a £ (or any other currency symbol) I only seem to get a weird little symbol ¤ which bares no results when searched.

Comment: @doug in the case you can pass the $currency (should be a string like 'EUR' ) somehow to the filter, then change the New formatter line for something like $formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale."@currency=$currency", \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);